# Two panel display using Java Swing that behaves as a tab control

Tags: java, swing, awt

In my Java application, I need to display a window with two vertical panels. The first panel displays some icons in a vertical column. When an icon is clicked, the second panel should show a corresponding panel. Those who are familiar with Videolan VLC, the preferences dialog in VLC displays something similar.

I searched the net. Looks like I might be able to make it work using CardLayout. However, I am wondering if the framework provides a better construct. I am thinking this is such a common design pattern, there must be something already established in the framework. Regards.

Comment: Yes, a `JList` (or `JToolBar` as mentioned by @icza) for the panel list in the `LINE_START` position, with a `CardLayout` in the `CENTER` (of a `BorderLayout`) is what I'd use for that component.  Show it in a modal dialog.

Answer (score 2):

For the "icons" panel you could use a [`JToolBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JToolBar.html). You can specify vertical orientation for the tool bar like this:

```
new JToolBar(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);
```

You can add the tool bar for the WEST or EAST side of a panel having a `BorderLayout` layout manager, and add the content to the CENTER of the panel.

As an alternative you could use a [`JTabbedPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html) and the tab placement to be on the left like this:

```
new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.LEFT);
```

That way you would not need to manage 2 panels. And the tabbed pane takes care of the content switching for you. If you want only icons, you can add tabs without a text:

```
tabbedPane.addTab("", icon, component); // empty string or you can use null
```

Answer (score 2):

- [`JTabbedPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html), set to show the key values to the left
- [`JList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) on the left, with a `JPanel` with a `CardLayout` on the right.  Each value from the `JList` could maintain the key for the `CardLayout` which would show the corresponding pane
- [`JTree`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html), configured correctly, well allow you to show hirarcal configuraiton elements...

Of course, you could just roll your own...

[image: Preferences]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/playlist.png"));
                System.out.println(getClass().getResource("playlist.png"));

                JPanel options = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
                gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
                gbc.weightx = 1;
                gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                gbc.insets = new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1);
                options.add(new ConfigPane("Playlist",
                                new String[]{"Playlist", "/playlist.png"},
                                new String[]{"Media Library", "/library.png"}), gbc);
                options.add(new ConfigPane("My Computer",
                                new String[]{"My Videos", "/movie.png"},
                                new String[]{"My Music", "/music.png"},
                                new String[]{"My Pictures", "/pictures.png"}), gbc);
                options.add(new ConfigPane("Devices",
                                new String[]{"Discs", "/disc.png"}), gbc);
                options.add(new ConfigPane("Local Network",
                                new String[]{"Universal Plug'n'Play", "/lan.png"},
                                new String[]{"Network streams", "/lan.png"}), gbc);
                options.add(new ConfigPane("Internet",
                                new String[]{"Podcasts", "/podcast.png"},
                                new String[]{"Assemblee Noationale", "/assembleenationale.png"},
                                new String[]{"Free Music Charts", "/fmc.png"},
                                new String[]{"Freebox TV", "/network.png"},
                                new String[]{"Icecast Radio Directory", "/icecast.png"},
                                new String[]{"Jamendo Selections", "/jamendo.png"},
                                new String[]{"Channels", "/metachannels.png"}
                ), gbc);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.gridx = 0;
                gbc.gridy = 0;
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(options), gbc);
                gbc.weighty = 1;
                gbc.gridy++;
                frame.add(new JPanel(), gbc);

                gbc.gridx++;
                gbc.gridy = 0;
                gbc.weightx = 1;
                gbc.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
                frame.add(new JPanel(), gbc);

                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ConfigPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel title;

        public ConfigPane(String name, String[]... options) {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            title = new JLabel(name);
            title.setFont(title.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1);

            add(title, gbc);

            for (String[] option : options) {
                System.out.println(option[0]);
                JLabel lblOption = new JLabel(option[0]);
                lblOption.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(option[1])));
                add(lblOption, gbc);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Of course, you'll need to know when the user clicks on each option and update the main screen accordingly...